# Turning my code into a better Swift like answer for a FizzBuzz response

Tags: swift, swift2

I was searching the internet last night while working on some programming, and I noticed that there was this interesting test that employers sometimes use for testing programmers to see if they can actually apply code to a real world problem. It is referred to as the FizzBuzz test, and it works like this.

> "Write a program that prints the numbers 1 to 100. But, for multiples
>   of 3, print "Fizz" instead of the number and for multiples of 5, print
>   "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print
>   "FizzBuzz"."

Now, I sat down and came up with this code very quickly, which I placed in my viewDidLoad method:

```
for i in 1...100 {
            if i % 3 = 0 && i % 5 == 0 {
                print("FizzBuzz")
            } else if i % 3 == 0 {
                print("Fizz")
            } else if i % 5 == 0 {
                print("Buzz")
            } else {
                print(i)
            }
        }
```

And, although this fulfils the brief, I feel very dissatisfied by using this as my solution (it seems too simple and basic to me).

I have recently read the book, iOS 9 Programming Fundamentals With Swift by Matt Neuburg (this book has blown my mind and opened my eyes in so many levels). And I am captivated by trying to make things as Swift-y as possible (passing functions, and the like). Then, I came to the sobering  and disheartening realisation that I really have no idea how to improve this code.

Therefore, I am turning to the Swift community in hopes that you could better educate me on what would be ***the most sophisticated Swift*** answer for the FiizBuzz test question.

I am desperately trying to improve my Swift programming and would like to know a better Swift-y programming approach to my code.

Comment: Relevant: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56805/is-this-fizzbuzz-swift-y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in a playground. It is an attempt at a functional approach. It is not efficient.

```
let range = (1...100)
let fizz  = range.map{ ($0 % 3 == 0) ? "Fizz" : "" }
let buzz  = range.map{ ($0 % 5 == 0) ? "Buzz" : "" }
zip(range, zip(fizz, buzz))
  .map {
    let fb = $1.0 + $1.1
    print(fb.isEmpty ? $0 : fb)
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Price Ringo, this is literally the sort of answer that I was looking forward to getting from everyone. Very nice, indeed.

Comment: Except if I was interviewing you and you gave this answer I wouldn't be that happy. It is both inefficient and more importantly difficult to read. Arguably for a loop size of 100 efficiency isn't that big a deal, but from a maintainability point of view it is awful.

Comment: I agree and stated as much in my answer. Swift has provided my first exposure to Functional Programming and I wanted to try to solve it that way. FP is not a panacea. The OP wanted the "most sophisticated Swift answer for the FiizBuzz test question" not the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

Following Dan's [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56805/is-this-fizzbuzz-swift-y) in comments I came up with:

```
for i in 1...100 {
  switch (i%3, i%5) {
  case (0,0): print("FizzBuzz")
  case (0,_): print("Fizz")
  case (_,0): print("Buzz")
  default: print(i)
  }
}
```

> 1
>   2
>   Fizz
>   4
>   Buzz
>   Fizz
>   7
>   8
>   Fizz
>   Buzz
>   11
>   Fizz
>   13
>   14
>   FizzBuzz
>   …

Comment: Kenneth Bruno, one thing that I notice immediately about your code is the ability to upscale or increase the number of parameters very easily (I know that its not part of the brief but still a very nice option). For instance, if you wanted to look at the event that the numbers are multiples of 3, 5, and 9. You can easily add the i%9 and then add case(0,0,0) plus appropriate code to satisfy the switch statement.

Comment: What I liked most when I saw the example that I built off of was that it's compact, clean, and readable. It's also fairly efficient. Tuples in `switch..case` statements are powerful.