# Trying to make a for loop that will output certain words based on multiples

Tags: swift, for-loop

I am new to Swift and I am trying to make a for loop that will output certain words based on multiples.

I want to output every number between 1 and 100, but for multiples of 3 I want to output a string that says Hey.  For multiples of 5 I want to output a string that says Hello.  Lastly, for multiples of both 3 and 5 I want to output a string that says Great.

This what I've got so far

```
for var i = 1; i <= 100; ++i {
if i / 3 {
    print("Hey")
}

else if i / 5 {
    print("Hello")
}

else if i / 3 && i / 5 {
    print("Great")
}

else {
    print(i)
}
}
```

Comment: this is a modified version of the fizz buzz problem / interview question, the answer being that you need to know about the % (modulus) operator

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35822835/887210

Comment: Thanks Wain and Kenneth

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in 1...100 {
        if n % 3 == 0 {
        print("Hey")
        }
        else if n % 5 == 0{
            print("Hello")
        }
        else if n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0 {
            print("Great")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a bit of optimization for code clarity. You don't need the first line, `for n in 1...100 {` works just as well. And a `switch..case` statement is usually more readable than a chain of `if..else`.

Comment: You need to put if n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0 {
        print("Great")
    } at the top because it will else never get called.

Answer (score 0):

// So you dont need to return anything if you just need to print it out
// also the enumerator does the counting for you so you don't need to pass // an argument with i

```
func fizzbuzz() {

    for i in 1...100 {

        if i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 {
            print("fizzbuzz")
        }

        else if i % 3 == 0 {
            print("fizz")
        }
        else if i % 5 == 0 {
            print("buzz")
        }
        else {
            print("\(i)")
        }
    }
}
```